# What should be considered when designing a file format?

Tags: xml, file-format

I am looking to create a file format for storing and sharing procedures to make chemicals from base elements. The format would need to define things such as quantities of each base element, written procedure, time required for the reaction to take place, qualitative information about the expected results, for example "cloudy, red, liquid" and so forth.

I really don't know the first thing about file formats, could someone direct me to where I should start, and / or give some tips on making the format universal and useable? My first instinct is to start from XML somehow, although I don't know much about that either.

I have misled you about the exact nature of what I'm designing, because it is secret until the release date, but my example should be sufficiently similar that any advice will still apply.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a *very* good reason, don't try to design your own file formats.  In virtually every field, there are already numerous conflicting file formats which make program compatibility a headache.  I encourage you to look for an existing, preferably open, file format which matches your needs.

If you do need to create a new format, XML is a good place to start.  XML is text based and allows for easy inspection, making it possible for the format to be used with little development work, and for years to come.  I also encourage you to research the domain (chemistry) and the potential applications of the file format, to make sure its capabilities match with the needs of the industry.

Comment: Whether is XML is good or not is under hot discussion. I'd rather suggest look at JSON/BSON or S-Expressions, as they simple and easier than XML.

Comment: I agree that XML is a pain for data transmission, but for storage, it is more popular than JSON.